# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'modules[moduleId].call') on using vue-cli/vue-router with layout-file

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I am facing this problem:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'modules[moduleId].call')

[image]

This is the tree of files:

```
├── README.md
├── babel.config.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── index.html
├── src
│   ├── App.vue
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── logo.png
│   │   └── tailwind.css
│   ├── components
│   │   └── HelloWorld.vue
│   ├── layouts
│   │   └── Layout1.vue
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── pages
│   │   └── Home
│   │       └── View.vue
│   ├── router
│   │   ├── home.js
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── store
│       └── index.js
├── tailwind.config.js
└── vue.config.js
```

This is the router's `index.js`

```
import Layout1 from '@/layouts/Layout1'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Layout1,
    children: [{
      path: '/',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home-view" */ '@/pages/Home/View.vue')
    }
    ]
  }]
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

This is `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      filename: () => (process.env.VUE_CLI_MODERN_MODE && !process.env.VUE_CLI_MODERN_BUILD) ? '[name].[hash:8].js' : '[name]-legacy.[hash:8].js'
    }
  }
}
```

The error message does not help a lot. So some module is not being found, but all paths are correct. Does anybody of you know what I messed up here?

Comment: dynamic import returns a promise, maybe like that? `component: async () => await import(/* webpackChunkName: "home-view" */ '@/pages/Home/View.vue')`

Comment: Did you find a solution that worked for you? Did the comment by @Ifaruki help you fix the error?

Answer (score -1):

CMD+ALT+E followed by a refresh CMD+R.[enter link description here][1]

[modules[moduleId] is undefined error is unhelpful #5429]: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5429